# How to pass events between an Itemrenderer and its parent

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a spark list control whose data is rendered using an itemrenderer. Basically the Item renderer lays out the data within a Panel.

The Panel has a LinkButton, which when clicked needs to pass an Id to the parent application. In the parent application I have a function that dispatches a custom event to its parent. I want to know how to call this function from the ItemRenderer.

I tried using parentDocument.outerfunction etc but it throws an error..

Any clues ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you were using PureMVC, you could send a notification that the receiver would handle and perform the needed work.  This is similar to firing a custom event and receiving it in the parent.

Answer (score 4):

I would have your item renderer dispatch a custom event that contains your Id, making sure that your event bubbles.  Then in the parent application listen for that event and call the appropriate function.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes i tried dat too... in my item renderer, I have registered my custom event. On the click of the linkbutton, i create an instance of the evnt and then dispatch it. However I have no clue how to handle it in the parent application. .. could u show me some code that will explain this ?

Comment: in your itemRenderer : new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM, true);
in your parent : addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM, customHandler)

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use bubble :
in your itemRenderer : new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM); 
in your parent : addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM, customHandler, true)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you can try to call from the item renderer this.parentApplication or this.parent.parent.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a custom event and bubble .. and add an event listener for that event in parent document..

Answer (score 0):

this is working I have test parentcomponent(this.owner.parent).function...owner is list and parent is the component in which list is placed e-g InvitationList(this.owner.parent).invitationAccepted(persist);
type cast the this.owner.parent to your parentclass